# What is the difference between building and installing CyanogenMod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

What is the difference between building and installing CyanogenMod? I am really confused.

I'm deciding whether or not I should install CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 2):

Building CyanogenMod requires developers tools and knowledge in actually converting the program source into binary code designated for your selected device/handset.

Installing CyanogenMod is just putting the actual zip of the ROM onto the SDCard and flashing it via ClockWorkMod Recovery which performs the install and prepares the environment on next reboot, this is somewhat, a once-off operation, unless you are into flashing ROMs on a regular basis.

Comment: so in the end, is it the same result?

Comment: Practically, its the same result at the end of it :)